# How do I call yum_package without internet connection from cache only?

Tags: chef-infra, yum

Part of the machines where we run chef on have no access to a yum-repository with basic packages (like openjdk).

In chef11 we managed to not trigger an internet connection by setting the parameters in `/etc/yum.conf`:

```
exclude=*
metadata_expire=2147483647
mirrorlist_expire=2147483647
```

In chef12, unfortunately, this is not sufficient anymore. We get an exception:

```
[2015-02-10T09:43:38+00:00] ERROR: yum_package[java-1.7.0-openjdk] (java::openjdk line 46) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout: Command timed out after 900s:
Command exceeded allowed execution time, process terminated
---- Begin output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
---- End output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 ----
Ran /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 returned 
[2015-02-10T09:43:38+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Is there a flag or hack to disable this call to yum-dump. We provide a basebox where the correct version of the packages is already installed?

I looked into some cache flags but did not find anything obvious either?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a cookbook file to drop a package local to a temp directory and then do

```
cookbook_file "/tmp/yourpackage-1.1.1.rpm" do
  source "yourpackage-1.1.1.rpm"
  action :create
end

package "yourpackage" do
  source "/tmp/yourpackage-1.1.1.rpm
  action :install
end
```